# jQuery: scrolling when scrollbar is at bottom

Tags: jquery, scroll

If I had a div, and wanted it to automatically scroll when its scrollbar was at the bottom, how would I do so with the code I have here? It does not work correctly for me.

```
var scroll = false;
if ($("#console").scrollTop() == ($("#console").prop("scrollHeight") - 503)) {
  scroll = true;
}
if (scroll == true) {
  $("#console").prop({ scrollTop: $("#console").prop("scrollHeight") });
}
```

How would I do this if the div's height was dynamic, instead of a static size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hexacyanide,

You need to attach an event handler to the container. What you have here now the code will always be false since you are not capturing any event that is happening.

Comment: See this example: http://api.jquery.com/scroll/

One way to do this is wrap your function above in function, and use $("#console").scroll(function(){ callMyFunc(); });

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#console").scroll(function(){
  var boxHeight = $('#console').height();
  if($("#console").scrollTop() == ($("#console").prop("scrollHeight") - boxHeight )) {
    $("#console").prop({ scrollTop: $("#console").prop("scrollHeight") });
  }
});
```

Can you try this new version, inspired by our fellow helper in here. This should work, as soon a you scroll, it will check if it's as the bottom or not. If it is, it will scroll back to the top.

Comment: I edited my code, it should work, the only thing I might not be sure is the scrollTop() == part .... It could be >= or <= I don't know I can't test it I hope it helps ! Btw credit to nolabel, I didn't use any listener now it should work as needed. Let me know.